# How to get list of multiple choices

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a problem rendering a template variable for example `{{ profile.speciality }}`
that resulted in `[u'pediatrics']` on the web page, what I actually wanted is simply
`pediatrics`. The data is coming from `MultipleChoiceField` and a `CheckboxSelectMultiple` 
widget, because user should be able to select multiple options.

Then i used `request.POST.getlist('speciality')` to populate data in to the model instance,
     for example:

```
user_profile = UserProfile(speciality=request.POST.getlist('speciality'))
```

I also tried to iterate over `{{ profile.speciality }}` in the template but what I am getting is string iteration rather than a list iteration.

I am an absolute beginner, I have no programming experience, pardon me if I did anything stupid, need help desperately, tried everything I could.

thank you

Comment: So you are using django forms to render the form in the template?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to render a MultipleChoiceField

```
{% for speciality in profile.speciality.all %}
    {{ speciality }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Cipran Crisan
i tried the suggestion,but then it's rendering nothing,thanks for the answer